# Converting string to date returns nil

Tags: swift, date, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert my string to a date using a static date formatter. When I make the call to `stringToDate()` using the variables below, a `nil` value is returned.

I've checked previous posts about this issue where people are saying it's because of the dateformatter `locale` or `timeZone`. However, that doesn't seem to be the issue in this case.

Does anyone know what the issue could be in this case? My code is below:

```
import Foundation

class DateHelper {

    private static let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
        df.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return df
    }()

    static func stringToDate(str: String, with dateFormat: String) -> Date? {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)

        return date
    }
}

var myDate = Date()
var dateStr = "2019-02-19T17:10:08+0000"

print(DateHelper.stringToDate(str: dateStr, with: "MMM d yyyy")) // prints nil
```

Comment: Don't change the `dateFormat` of the shared `dateFormatter` instance. You're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Not to mention that none of the date formats in your code match the string `"2019-02-19T17:10:08+0000"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dateformatter returns nil date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325788/dateformatter-returns-nil-date)

Comment: 2019-02-19T17:10:08+0000 and yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format not match. please search solution. There are lots of solution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your string is in ISO8601 format. Use the [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/1643127-date) to get date instance. You can use [ISO8601DateFormatter.Options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/options) to parse varieties of [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For your string,

For Swift 4.2.1

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr)
print(date!)
```

Should output

`"2019-02-19 17:10:08 +0000\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Your date format doesn't match your input date. Try this code:

```
print(DateHelper.stringToDate(str: dateStr, with: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"))
```

Hope this helps.